# Error de subconsulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Estoy haciendo una migración codigo de SQL server a MySql y casi todo perfecto excepto por este SELECT

```
SELECT
     User_role.cd_role_type `User Type`,
     COUNT(User_role.cd_role_type) `Total Active`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM User_Profile AS User_Profile_sub
            INNER JOIN User_role AS User_role_sub ON User_role_sub.id_user = User_Profile_sub.id_user AND User_role_sub.cd_role_type=User_role.cd_role_type AND User_role_sub.in_status=1
        WHERE 
            (User_Profile_sub.nm_middle='' OR User_Profile_sub.nm_middle IS NULL)
            AND User_Profile_sub.id_user > 0
    ) `No Middle Name`
FROM User_Profile
    INNER JOIN User_role ON User_role.id_user = User_Profile.id_user AND User_role.in_status=1
WHERE 
    User_Profile.id_user > 0
GROUP BY 
    User_role.cd_role_type
```

Me lanza un `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'User_role.cd_role_type' in 'on clause'` este error me sucede en el INNER de la subconsulta en esta parte `User_role_sub.cd_role_type=User_role.cd_role_type`.

No tengo una idea clara de que puede esta ocurriendo ya que en SQL Server puedo usar columnas de el SELECT superior.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo así:

```
SELECT
     User_role.cd_role_type `User Type`,
     COUNT(User_role.cd_role_type) `Total Active`,(
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM User_Profile AS User_Profile_sub
            INNER JOIN User_role AS User_role_sub
            ON User_role_sub.id_user = User_Profile_sub.id_user
            AND User_role_sub.cd_role_type=User_Profile_sub.cd_role_type
            AND User_role_sub.in_status=1
        WHERE (User_Profile_sub.nm_middle='' 
            OR User_Profile_sub.nm_middle IS NULL)
            AND User_Profile_sub.id_user > 0
    ) `No Middle Name`
FROM User_Profile
    INNER JOIN User_role 
    ON User_role.id_user = User_Profile.id_user 
    AND User_role.in_status=1
WHERE 
    User_Profile.id_user > 0
GROUP BY 
    User_role.cd_role_type;
```

Es que has utilizado el nombre original de la tabla en vez del alias que le habías asignado.

Una vez que asignas un alias, el nombre original deja de estar disponible.

Comment: Nada no me funciono para mi. La idea mia es compararlo con los id de select externo. Aplico eso en SQL y funciona, pero aca no funciona.

Comment: Mucho me extraña que el SQL al que haces referencia se salte las reglas del álgebra relacional, pero bueno, empecemos por el principio: modifica su pregunta incluyendo la estructura de tu base de datos, con unos registros de ejemplo (phpMyAdmin, Exportar), cuéntanos qué quieres conseguir con esa consulta y qué resultado esperas obtener a partir de los registros de muestra. Con suerte, hasta la optimizamos.